# Internet with WIfi adapter really slow

Tags: networking, drivers

i just got ubuntu 17.10 (never used Ubuntu before) and the Internet is really slow compairing to Windows (about 20% and unstable) . Can somebody help me ? I guess its a driver problem:

my lsmod :

```
Module Size Used by
rtl8xxxu 126976 0
rt2800usb 28672 0
rt2x00usb 20480 1 rt2800usb
rt2800pci 16384 0
rt2800mmio 16384 1 rt2800pci
rt2x00pci 16384 1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio 16384 2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
eeprom_93cx6 16384 1 rt2800pci
ccm 20480 6
arc4 16384 2
nls_iso8859_1 16384 1
snd_hda_codec_realtek 94208 1
snd_hda_codec_generic 73728 1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi 49152 1
snd_hda_intel 40960 8
snd_hda_codec 126976 4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_gen eric,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core 81920 5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd _hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep 20480 1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm 98304 4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_c odec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi 16384 0
snd_seq_midi_event 16384 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi 32768 1 snd_seq_midi
rt2800lib 114688 3 rt2800mmio,rt2800usb,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib 53248 7 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb ,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
snd_seq 65536 2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
edac_mce_amd 28672 0
mac80211 778240 5 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rtl8xxxu
snd_seq_device 16384 3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer 32768 2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
kvm 581632 0
cfg80211 610304 2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
input_leds 16384 0
joydev 20480 0
irqbypass 16384 1 kvm
snd 81920 27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_ timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec _generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_ pcm
soundcore 16384 1 snd
crct10dif_pclmul 16384 0
crc32_pclmul 16384 0
ccp 73728 0
ghash_clmulni_intel 16384 0
pcbc 16384 0
aesni_intel 188416 4
eeepc_wmi 16384 0
aes_x86_64 20480 1 aesni_intel
asus_wmi 28672 1 eeepc_wmi
crypto_simd 16384 1 aesni_intel
glue_helper 16384 1 aesni_intel
sparse_keymap 16384 1 asus_wmi
shpchp 36864 0
i2c_piix4 24576 0
cryptd 24576 3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
video 40960 1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof 16384 0
8250_dw 16384 0
mac_hid 16384 0
parport_pc 32768 0
ppdev 20480 0
lp 20480 0
parport 49152 3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables 24576 0
x_tables 40960 1 ip_tables
autofs4 40960 2
hid_generic 16384 0
usbhid 49152 0
hid 118784 2 hid_generic,usbhid
amdkfd 188416 1
amd_iommu_v2 20480 1 amdkfd
amdgpu 2007040 31
i2c_algo_bit 16384 1 amdgpu
ttm 94208 1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper 167936 1 amdgpu
syscopyarea 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops 16384 1 drm_kms_helper
drm 356352 27 amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
r8169 81920 0
ahci 36864 2
mii 16384 1 r8169
libahci 32768 1 ahci
wmi 24576 2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
gpio_amdpt 16384 0
gpio_generic 16384 1 gpio_amdpt
```

my " sudo lshw -C network" :

```
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:1e:00.0
logical name: enp30s0
version: 15
serial: 88:d7:f6:40:30:13
size: 10Mbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
resources: irq:296 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe604000-fe604fff memory:fe600000-fe603fff
*-network
description: Wireless interface
physical id: 1
bus info: usb@1:9
logical name: wlx98ded0088d44
serial: 98:de:d0:08:8d:44
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.13.0-16-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.7 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

lsusb :

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c07e Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:0108  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Wifi Analysis : https://pastebin.com/g2PeXf75

EDIT : I tried some WLAN Adapters and these are the results of the best one.
THANKS for any help !

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, i edited the question, thanks for your input !

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi David, thanks for your advice, here is the log file : https://pastebin.com/g2PeXf75

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your router is set to channel 9. This channel is subject to considerable overlap from other nearby networks: https://superuser.com/questions/443178/is-it-better-to-use-a-crowded-2-4ghz-wi-fi-channel-1-6-11-or-unused-3-4-8

Please try resetting the router to channel 1 or 6 or 11 to see if there is any improvement.

Next, we  see this:

```
##### iw reg get ########################
Region: Europe/Paris (based on set time zone)   
global 
country DE: DFS-ETSI
```

I recommend that your country code be set correctly, if not Germany (DE).

Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Any improvement?

Comment: Well it didnt get any better but thanks for your effort :)