# Connected to WiFi but websites are not loading in Firefox (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.10

I recently installed some minor updates on my Ubuntu 18.10. Since then, I do not have internet access anymore. The wifi symbol in the top right corner indicates that I am connected to a wireless network but I just do not have internet access. My phone is connected to the same wireless network and it works just fine.

```
jonas@ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=31.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=79.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=94.3 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.506/68.499/94.268/26.824 ms
jonas@ubuntu:~$ ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
PING www.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.115) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www-ubuntu-com.privet.canonical.com (91.189.89.115): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=26.8 ms
64 bytes from www-ubuntu-com.privet.canonical.com (91.189.89.115): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=28.9 ms

--- www.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 2 received, 33.3333% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.790/27.855/28.920/1.065 ms
jonas@ubuntu:~$
```

Running *lsmod* in the terminal yields the following:

```
jonas@ubuntu:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  1
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             208896  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
kvm                   622592  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
uvcvideo               98304  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
btusb                  45056  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
videobuf2_common       45056  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
videodev              188416  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
media                  40960  2 videodev,uvcvideo
i915                 1740800  10
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                20480  1 btusb
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
drm_kms_helper        172032  1 i915
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
joydev                 20480  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
thinkpad_acpi          94208  1
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
drm                   458752  5 drm_kms_helper,i915
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
arc4                   16384  2
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
iwldvm                229376  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
mac80211              794624  1 iwldvm
ecdh_generic           24576  2 bluetooth
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
iwlwifi               294912  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              663552  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
video                  45056  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof
snd                    81920  18 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_i801               28672  0
mac_hid                16384  0
mei_me                 40960  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     36864  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   126976  4 usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
gpio_ich               16384  0
ahci                   40960  4
libahci                32768  1 ahci
psmouse               151552  0
r8169                  86016  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
rtsx_pci               65536  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
mii                    16384  1 r8169
jonas@ubuntu:~$
```

And ...

```
jonas@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf | tail -n1
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`

Comment: If you can ping ubuntu.com, even haltingly, you have internet access. Let's turn our attention to the wireless driver. Please run: `lsmod` Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: It is not super long so I added it to my question :)

Comment: you have internet conncetion now? ping to ubuntu.com success

Comment: Have you undertaken all the router steps from here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/967369/internet-with-wifi-adapter-really-slow/967397#967397 Also, may we see: `cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf | tail -n1`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support! In the meantime, I realized that my Thunderbird still received emails so indeed, I must have had internet access. Still, web pages in Firefox were not loading. I checked whether other applications that rely on internet were working e.g. the software center and it did. I installed Chromium and it works just fine. Firefox still does not load web pages so it seems to be an issue with Firefox. However, I do not care if I use Firefox or Chromium so this solution is also fine for me. Thank you all for your comments and support.